# Anyone know what key this is for my anti theft wheel bolts?

Tags: wheels, security, bolts

Does anyone know what type of key this is for my anti wheel theft bolts?  It's from a VW Golf Mk5 but I don't know if it's OEM.  Has a "H" on the back - no number.

[image: Key]

Thanks for any help

Comment: H ids for Hammered... If it is OEM, then a dealer will be able to get you a replacement (but you may, or may not, like the price). But the original locking nuts on my car were removed - too old for people to want to nick the wheels now...

Answer (score 1):

Rule #1 don't use impact drivers on locking lug nuts.  It looks like a McGard lock. However they have been around long enough for there to be cheaply made knock-off brands. All is not lost though. They actually sell special sockets just to remove locking lug nuts. Which makes you wonder how effective they really are.